# How to setup an environment in anaconda and python 32 bit version on Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

right now im using Anaconda 64 Bit (latest version) on Windows 10 64 Bit and i need to work with python 64 bit and 32 bit cause I have to work with a 32 bit driver in my python programm.

Maybe somebody can help me cause I dont know how i can change the python bit version.
I also tried the command CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1 but it doesnt work. Some help would be really great ;).

Thanks in advance
Littlestudent